# Select only columns where entries have only one number/character by ignoring NAs

Tags: r, matrix

I have following matrix:

```
r1 <- c("1","01","001","0001","01","100")
r2 <- c("1","10","001","0001","10","100")
r3 <- c("1","01","100","1000","10","010")
r4 <- c("1","01","010","0100",NA,"001")
r5<- c(NA, "01","010","0010","10","001")

n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
```

And I would like to remove columns containing only one character as it is in column one (in the example). And I would like to ignore the NAs. So even if there is a NA in the first column (NA is obviously of two characters) I would like to remove it.
So the output should look like this:

```
r1 <- c("01","001","0001","01","100")
r2 <- c("10","001","0001","10","100")
r3 <- c("01","100","1000","10","010")
r4 <- c("01","010","0100",NA,"001")
r5 <- c("01","010","0010","10","001")

n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
```

At the moment I have this command, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
n.mat[apply(n.mat, 2, sum) > 1, ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `colSums` to select columns which have more than 1 character in them.

```
n.mat[, colSums(nchar(n.mat) > 1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0]

#   [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4] [,5] 
#r1 "01" "001" "0001" "01" "100"
#r2 "10" "001" "0001" "10" "100"
#r3 "01" "100" "1000" "10" "010"
#r4 "01" "010" "0100" NA   "001"
#r5 "01" "010" "0010" "10" "001"
```

Comment: Your solution will omit values like "11" or "222" because of the use of ```unique``` call. Better use ```nchar```

Comment: Yes, I had a wrong answer earlier. I corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
n.mat[,apply(nchar(n.mat),2,max,na.rm=T)>1]
   [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4] [,5] 
r1 "01" "001" "0001" "01" "100"
r2 "10" "001" "0001" "10" "100"
r3 "01" "100" "1000" "10" "010"
r4 "01" "010" "0100" NA   "001"
r5 "01" "010" "0010" "10" "001"
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> n.mat[, apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) sum(nchar(x), na.rm = 1)/sum(!is.na(x)) > 1)]
   [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4] [,5] 
r1 "01" "001" "0001" "01" "100"
r2 "10" "001" "0001" "10" "100"
r3 "01" "100" "1000" "10" "010"
r4 "01" "010" "0100" NA   "001"
r5 "01" "010" "0010" "10" "001"
```